# sed - how to replace either space or underscore_word

Tags: sed

Currently I have this sed:

```
sed -i '/[^}.to]\.to[[:space:]]/ s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/' ../_spec_seded/"$file"
```

which adds "`expect(`" at the start of lines that have "`.to`" (but not "`{.to`")

How can I make this so that it matches lines with both "`.to`" and also "`.to_not`"?

I tried

```
sed -i '/[^}.to]\.to([[:space:]]|_not)/ s/\(\S\)/expect(\1/' my_file
```

basically changing `[[:space:]]` to `([[:space:]]|_not)` to try and match `.to` OR `.to_not` but this messed it up for both, not adding the expect at the start.

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: w/o seeing the data, seems like you could do a .to|.to_not.

Comment: will try but bit hard as this is in the middle of other sed operations.  I did update the Q a little (removed 'start' of line for the `.to`).

Comment: I can't see what you're actually trying to do. What's with the [[:space:]]?

Comment: Is that `}` flipped in pattern vs. *but not "`{.to`"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
sed '/{\.to/b;/\.to\(_not\|\)\s/s/^\s*/\0expect(/' file
```

alt:

```
sed '/{\.to/b;/\.to\(_not\|\)[[:space:]]/s/^[[:space:]]*/\0expect(/' file
```

Sample:

```
$ diff -ytW 48 infile <(./sed_script)
.to do                 |  expect(.to do
  .to SPACE and        |    expect(.to SPACE and
        .to TAB        |          expect(.to TAB
some s                    some s
day x                     day x
.to r                  |  expect(.to r
.tofry                    .tofry
not t                     not t
.to     tab            |  expect(.to      tab
{.to not me               {.to not me
{.to nor me               {.to nor me
when e                    when e
        {.to Nope                 {.to Nope
.to_not BUT yes!       |  expect(.to_not BUT yes
  {.to Oh nono              {.to Oh nono
.to_notX                  .to_notX
.do s                     .do s
{.to not do me            {.to not do me
so d                      so d

|--- Original file ----|--- modified file ----|
```